# UITabBarController as master of SplitViewController causes view cutoff issue

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using the latest Xcode version 13.1, also tried in Xcode 12. I am trying to add UITabBarController as a master view of UISplitViewController using just a storyboard (no code involved) as shown in the screenshot attached but I am getting a weird issue where the tab bars items are cut off (screenshot attached) and the whole view of TabBarController is not visible. Searched through google and also tried with different options in the storyboard but I am stuck with this issue for hours.

Is there any solution for this? Has anyone been able to resolve this issue in the current Xcode version? Any help is highly appreciable.

**Storyboard**
[image]
**Result**
[image]
As can be seen that all tabbar items are not visible at all and Item1 is cut off.

Comment: I think UITabBarController doesn't respect the new iOS 14 column style by not updating the leading margin. Instead it defaults to the 420pt width. Haven't found a solution yet. See also [this tweet](https://twitter.com/geoffhackworth/status/1283802290613354498).